# PHP Title Formatting

Tags: php

I have a CMS script. I need help about title formatting.
Example:

user defines format as: "Watch %v at %s"

%v is video name and %s is site name.

Comment: What is your question?  Please add much more detail, and see the FAQ here:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)

```
$videoName = 'foo';
$siteName = 'bar';
$output = 'Watch %s at %s';
printf($output, $videoName, $siteName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the PHP function [`sprintf()`](http://www.php.net/sprintf)

Comment: Thank you everyone! sprintf() is the what i am looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
mixed str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )

<?php
// Provides: <body text='black'>
$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");
<?php
```